# DJANGO Issue with ManyToManyField in Form

Tags: django, forms, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

First of all english isn't my main language so please don't yell on me ;)

I have model with ManyToManyField. And I made for this form, but i can't add new items with this form. My kode looks like that:

forms.py

```
class NoteForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    author = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = forms.TexField()
    type = forms.CharField(max_length = 10)
    disciple = forms.ManyToManyField(queryset=Disciple.objects.all())
```

views.py

```
def new_note(request):
    note = Diary.objects.all()
    disc = Disciple.objects.all()
    form = NoteForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        note_form = form.save(commit=False)
        data = request.POST.copy()
        note_form.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
        note_form.author = form.cleaned_data['author']
        note_form.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
        note_form.type = form.cleaned_data['type']
        note_form.disciple = form.cleaned_data['disciple']
        for item in  note_form.disciple:
            note_form.disciple.add(item)
        note_form.save()
        form = NoteForm()
        return render_to_response('dziennik/users.html', {'note': note, 'form': form},
                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
            return render_to_response('dziennik/new_note.html', {'note': note, 'form': form},
                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And when im trying to add new object im getting error in this line:

> note_form.disciple = form.cleaned_data['disciple']

And the error is:

```
"Diary: Diary object" needs to have a value for field "diary" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

I don't know how to fix it and i can't go further without it.

Comment: There's no such thing as `forms.ManyToManyField`. Please show real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `note_form.save()` before adding `ManyToMany` objects not after.

```
note_form.save()
for item in  note_form.disciple:
    note_form.disciple.add(item)
```

Comment: Oke i fixed that, but still have same error. Because current error i have in line above.

Comment: As pointed out by Daniel there is no such filed as `forms.ManyToManyField` did you mean `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField`? Have you implemented the form save method? Please post complete form with real code.

Comment: Hmm... I won't argue, but i have forms.ManyToManyField in my forms.py. And this is whole code for my form, without imports ofc.
And thank you very much Aamir you helped me alot. I made it. I just put 'note_form.save()' above this problematic line and it's working :)